# How can I decrease distance between equations?

Tags: equations, line-spacing

I have this code and I want to decrease the vertical distance between equations? Can anyone help me?

```
\begin{equation}\label{20}
P_{\ell}^k\geq -P_\ell^{\max}\cdot Z_\ell^k~~\forall \ell\in\Omega^L,~\forall k\in\Omega^{K}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{21}
-P_{\ell}^k\geq -P_\ell^{\max}\cdot Z_\ell^k~~\forall \ell\in\Omega^L,~\forall k\in\Omega^{K}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{22}
\begin{split}
\frac{P_\ell^k}{B_\ell}-(\theta_{\textrm{FB}(\ell)}^k&-\theta_{\textrm{TB}(\ell)}^k)\geq -M_\ell(1-Z_\ell^k)\\&~~\forall \ell\in\Omega^L,\forall k\in\Omega^{K}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: @Mico sigh, sorry:-) (I zapped the comment:-)

Answer (score 1):

Rather strange usage of `align`, but the result similar to the original one. Additional decreasing may be obtained by an optional parameter of `\\`, e.g. `\\[-1pt]`, but I do not reccomend it in this case.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Original

\begin{equation}\label{20}
P_{\ell}^k\geq -P_\ell^{\max}\cdot Z_\ell^k~~\forall \ell\in\Omega^L,~\forall k\in\Omega^{K}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{21}
-P_{\ell}^k\geq -P_\ell^{\max}\cdot Z_\ell^k~~\forall \ell\in\Omega^L,~\forall k\in\Omega^{K}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{22}
\begin{split}
\frac{P_\ell^k}{B_\ell}-(\theta_{\textrm{FB}(\ell)}^k&-\theta_{\textrm{TB}(\ell)}^k)\geq -M_\ell(1-Z_\ell^k)\\&~~\forall \ell\in\Omega^L,\forall k\in\Omega^{K}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Modified

\begin{align}\label{20}
&P_{\ell}^k
\geq -P_\ell^{\max}\cdot Z_\ell^k~~\forall \ell\in\Omega^L,~\forall k\in\Omega^{K}
\\
\label{21}
&-P_{\ell}^k\geq -P_\ell^{\max}\cdot Z_\ell^k~~\forall \ell\in\Omega^L,~\forall k\in\Omega^{K}
\\
\label{22}
\begin{split}
\frac{P_\ell^k}{B_\ell}-(\theta_{\textrm{FB}(\ell)}^k-\theta_{\textrm{TB}(\ell)}^k)\geq -M_\ell(1-Z_\ell^k)\\~~\forall \ell\in\Omega^L,\forall k\in\Omega^{K}
\end{split}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd be tempted to insert `\phantom{-}` after the very first `&` to achieve a better alignment of the material on the first two rows.

Comment: `&-P` causes a wrong spacing; it should be `&{-}P`. However it should probably be `gather` rather than `align`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that (a) uses a `gather` environment to collect the three equations, (b) uses `\phantom{-}` at the start of the first equation to help achieve a natural alignment of the first and second rows, (c) doesn't split the third equation across two lines, and (d) uses `\smash[t]{...}` on the fractional term at the start of the third equation to achieve tighter spacing. I also suggest using `\quad` instead of `~~`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
\phantom{-}P_{\ell}^k
\geq -P_\ell^{\max}\cdot Z_\ell^k 
   \quad \forall \ell\in\Omega^L,\ \forall k\in\Omega^{K} \label{20} \\
{-}P_{\ell}^k\geq -P_\ell^{\max}\cdot Z_\ell^k
   \quad\forall \ell\in\Omega^L,\ \forall k\in\Omega^{K} \label{21} \\
\smash[t]{\frac{P_\ell^k}{B_\ell}}
   -\bigl(\theta_{\textrm{FB}(\ell)}^k-\theta_{\textrm{TB}(\ell)}^k\bigr)
   \geq -M_\ell(1-Z_\ell^k)
   \quad \forall \ell\in\Omega^L,\ \forall k\in\Omega^{K} \label{22}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```